# Problem for transferring file

Tags: linux

I Have two remote servers like A and B.

A is generating the dump of some tables from a database lets say (abc.sql).I want to transfer abc.sql to B.One option is scp but i didn't want to use because password opened to network.

can I get it directly from the B using wget.

on A the abc.sql have location /mnt/dump_of_tables/abc.sql.

How I will get it on B using wget please help.

Comment: What does "password opened to network" mean? `scp` is based off `ssh`, so it's secure.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524960/problem-for-transferring-file

Answer (score 0):

wget will require you to set up a web server to get the file.  I am pretty sure you don't want to do that.

If you don't want to use a password, you can still use scp by using public keys.  Use ssh_keygen to create a public/private keypair.  The id_rsa stays on the client machine in ~/.ssh and the id_rsa.pub contents should be added to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine.  If this file doesn't exist then copy id_rsa.pub over to the machine in the .ssh folder and rename to authorized_keys.  Change the permissions of the file to 600.